# ignore delimiters replaceall java

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

Is it possible to ignore delimiters when using regex expressions and the Java `String.replaceAll()` method?

*For `example:*

```
 String input_string = "test, testing, test";
 String regex_expression = "(test)(,|$)";
 String replace_expression = "foo";
 String output_string = input_string.replaceAll(regex_expression, replace_expression)
```

- current result: "foo testing, foo"
- desired result: "foo, testing, foo"

I need to search for delimiters in the regex expression, but I want to ignore them when doing the replace.

Comment: What is the logic here?

Comment: I've marked your code up as code for you. In the future can you mark up your code correctly?

Comment: Just do `"foo\\2"`.

Answer (score 3):

You keep changing your question, but this answer fits the current edition.  You may use a lookahead assertion to handle the replacement logic.

```
String input_string = "test, testing, test";
String output_string = input_string.replaceAll("test(?=,|$)", "foo");
```

Actually, my answer is very similar to what you already have.  The only difference is that the lookahead I used does not comsume the comma, which you appear to not want.